# Getting an Error while defining class which inherits from class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods

I need help to figure it out am I defining the Turtle class wrong way.
Below is my code:

class Animal:

```
name = ""
category = ""

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

def set_category(self, category):
    self.category = category
```

**# define a Turtle class that inherits from the Animal class**

class Turtle(Animal):

```
category = "reptile"
```

print(Turtle.category)

**I am getting following error:**

**NameError**
Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

----> 1 print(Turtle.category)

NameError: name 'Turtle' is not defined

What am I doing wrong? Actually I tried to do it in Jupyter notebook, it doesn't work but If I tried in IDE it works Perfectly. Why is it happening?

Comment: It's unclear above what's your code and what's your commentary on the code.  Could you please re-edit?  I'm assuming both "class" statements actually should be code.

Comment: I hope now you understand. I edited my code for better understanding. Thank you

Comment: Nope. I assume that the "class Animal" and the "class Turtle" lines, as well as the print statement are part of your code, too.  You need to give readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Turtle(Animal):
    category = "reptile"

print(Turtle.category)
reptile
```

look for the spacing and before running code restart and run code from the beginning.

Comment: If you look carefully , you will notice I did the same